# How many ways can I pick 10 coins using 5 different coins?

Tags: probability

I need to choose 10 coins using pennies, dimes, quarters, nickels, and half dollars and I'm not sure I'm doing it right. What I have is 14 choose 4 which is 1001 which doesn't seem like enough but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: 14 choose 4 is actually correct! is there a reason you think it maybe wrong ?

Comment: I don't know but as was thinking about it in my head and thinking about 5 different coins in 10 different spots it just seemed like it would be bigger. Now the second part its the same thing but only 5 of each coin, would it just be 9 choose 4?

Comment: I see... please check once stars and bars link I gave in the answer. Key thing is to notice that we can choose $0$ for any type of coins also.

Comment: Oh I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be number of pennies chosen, $d$ be number of dimes etc...
 We want to have 
$$p+d+q+n+h = 10$$

Using [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) the number of nonnegative solutions would be
$$\binom{10+5-1}{5-1} = \binom{14}{4}$$